# How to render div class conditionally in razor page based on a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to render div class based on a condition in Angular?

```
  <div class="@(myArray.length>0 ? "col-md-8" : "col-md-12" )">
```

I want that if myArray length is greater than 0 then it should be col-md-8 else it should be col-md-12.

I have defined $scope.myArray =[] inside script tag.

Comment: This syntax actually looks correct.  What happens when you try it?

Comment: @flashsplat It says 'The name myArray does not exist in the current context'. Even though I have defined $scope.myArray =[] inside script tag.

Comment: You probably need to define it in razor syntax like:  `@{ string[] myArray = new string[1]; }` If your array is in javascript, it would be better to use addClass or removeClass me thinks.  I've found the timing between the two is unpredictable.

Comment: I did     var finalObject = new Array[1];
It says Array[] does not contain a definition for 'length' ,

Comment: did you try capital L?  Length?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to do this in either Javascript or Razor, but not both.

If your array is coming from your controller, you can define myArray in **razor**.  Just put it in `@{ }` tags.  More detail here: https://forums.asp.net/post/4532657.aspx

If **javascript**, just set it up like:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="setCols">
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
if (typeof myArray != "undefined"  
            && myArray != null  
            && myArray.length > 0) 
    $(".setCols").addClass("col-md-8"); 
else 
    $(".setCols").addClass("col-md-12");
```

These may not be 100% sytaxically correct, but hopefully sets you on the right path.